# Html + PHP contact form (Page Not found)

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple Html page `index.html` where the user can submit a message. An additional PHP file `email_form.php` is created to capture the form submissions and send the form contents to my email address.

index.html:

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="email_form.php">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col" id="prenom">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom" required="True" name="prenom">
       </div>

       <div class="col" id="nom">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom" required="True" name="nom">
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="age">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required="True" name="age">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col" id="tel">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Téléphone" name="tel">
      </div>

      <div class="col" id="mail">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
      </div>
   </div>

   <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Your message" name="message"></textarea>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6" id="button">
       <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

email_form.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email_to = "info@mysite.com";
    $email_subject = "Email subject";

    $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom']; 
    $age = $_POST['age']; 
    $tel = $_POST['tel']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Prénom: ".clean_string($prenom)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Nom: ".clean_string($nom)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Age: ".clean_string($age)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = "From: ".$email."\n\n";
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
}   
?>
```

On the website, when I try to submit a message, it redirects me to a link looking like this: `mysite.com/email_form.php` with an error saying "page not found". I don't know much about PHP and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is email_form.php in the same directory as your index page? What kind of server environment are you running? PHP may not work out of the box without setting some server directives to handle PHP files.

Comment: Show us your file/folder structure (in the form of a tree view).

Comment: The `email_form.php` is in the same directory as the `index.html` page. But I didn't know about the server environment. Do I need it even though I'm not working on my `localhost` ?

Comment: @TomsRiver It seems you don't have that `php` file on server as you said `Do I need it even though I'm not working on my localhost?` How would it work on server without that file? Yes, you need to have it on server as well.

Comment: Of course the file is in save directory and server as `index.html`. I though @tshimkus was talking about an additional server specific for `email_form.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by changing `header`in email_form.php. Now it looks like this:

```
header("Location: https://example.com");
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a closing form tag `</form>`

Then:

1. Paste the php code to the top of your HTML file and
2. Change the file's extension to .php
3. Change the form's action to index.php

Your index.php should look something like this:

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email_to = "info@mysite.com";
    $email_subject = "Email subject";

    $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom']; 
    $age = $_POST['age']; 
    $tel = $_POST['tel']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Prénom: ".clean_string($prenom)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Nom: ".clean_string($nom)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Age: ".clean_string($age)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = "From: ".$email."\n\n";
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
}   
?>

  <form name="contactform" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col" id="prenom">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom" required="True" name="prenom">
        </div>

        <div class="col" id="nom">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom" required="True" name="nom">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col" id="age">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required="True" name="age">
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col" id="tel">
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Téléphone" name="tel">
        </div>

        <div class="col" id="mail">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Your message" name="message"></textarea>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6" id="button">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Separating the form and the PHP-code into two different files is actually recommended. That doesn't just give you cleaner files, it will also be much easier to reuse the code. (Btw, the redirect in your code goes to index.html, not index.php)